# Probability of the event that one player has an ace and the other has none.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

So four players get 13 card out of a deck of 52, and one player saw that one of the other players has an ace of diamonds. What's the probability that he himself has no aces in his hand.

There are ${{48}\choose{13}}{{38}\choose{13}}{{25}\choose{13}}$ ways the event that he has no aces can play out. First one of the other players get the ace of diamonds that he saw, that he gets $13$ of the $48$ that don't include aces, and then the other three players divide the rest of the card among themselves.

There are ${{51}\choose{13}}{{38}\choose{13}}{{25}\choose{13}}$ way that one of the players gets an ace of diamonds.

So probability is in my opinion ${{48}\choose{13}}{{38}\choose{13}}{{25}\choose{13}}/{{51}\choose{13}}{{38}\choose{13}}{{25}\choose{13}}$

Comment: It rather depends on whether he saw the other player had (i) the ace of diamonds and no other aces, or (ii) the ace of diamonds and 12 unknown cards.  Strangely, the answer to (ii) is different if the suit of the ace is unknown.

Comment: The second option is the one I'm interested in. What changes if the suit is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation looks correct though in this example I would have gone straight for the equivalent ${{48}\choose{13}}/{{51}\choose{13}} \approx 0.405$.

You asked in a comment how this might change if you did not know the suit, but just that the opponent had at least one ace, without knowing the suit.

$$\frac{  {4 \choose 1}  {48 \choose 12} {36 \choose 13} + {4 \choose 2}  {48 \choose 11} {37 \choose 13}+ {4 \choose 3}  {48 \choose 10} {38 \choose 13} + {4 \choose 4}  {48 \choose 9} {39 \choose 13} }{ {4 \choose 1}  {48 \choose 12} {39 \choose 13}+ {4 \choose 2}  {48 \choose 11} {39 \choose 13} +{4 \choose 3}  {48 \choose 10} {39 \choose 13}+{4 \choose 4}  {48 \choose 9} {39 \choose 13} } \approx 0.357.$$